# Triple Join In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How can I get the red section of the following Venn diagram in SQL 
[image: Venn Diag]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? What are A, B & C? What are the elements of the sets? If rows of tables, what if there are duplicatesor nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Joins` you can get any portion of Ven diagram, Somethink like below for your scenario.

```
select c.* 
from TableC c
left join TableA a on a.id = c.id 
left join TableB b on b.id = c.id
Where a.id is null and b.id is null -- Records which does not match in both tables
```

Answer (score 3):

I would think first of `except`:

```
select c.*
from c
except
select a.*
from a
except 
select b.*
from b;
```

My next thought would be `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = c.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = c.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is gonna be a bit of handwaving considering you are not giving actual table structures, but something like this:

```
Select c.name
From c
Where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = c.id)
  And not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = c.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` (assuming `id` is the common attribute):

```
SELECT c.id FROM c 
WHERE c.id NOT IN (SELECT a.id FROM a)
AND c.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id FROM b);
```